# Como tornar um ion-radio requerido, ou tornar o botão inativo enquanto não escolher uma opção?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Como posso tornar um ion-radio como requerido, ou desativar o botão se nada for selecionado?

```
  <ion-radio ng-model="escolhido.categoria_comida_cod_categoria_com" ng-value="'{{item.categoria_comida_cod_categoria_com}}'" ng-required="true">{{item.categoria_comida_nome}}</ion-radio>
```

Segue com o botão:

```
 <ion-list ng-repeat="item in categoriass | filter:q as results" ng-init="$last ? fireEvent() : null">

            <ion-radio ng-model="escolhido.categoria_comida_cod_categoria_com" ng-value="'{{item.categoria_comida_cod_categoria_com}}'" ng-required="true">{{item.categoria_comida_nome}}</ion-radio>
        </ion-list>


        <div class="spacer" style="width: 300px; height: 40px;"></div>

        <button class="button button-full button-assertive" ng-click="SelecionaCategoria(escolhido)">
            Continuar (Passo 1 de 2)
        </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizei POG (Programação orientada a gambiarra)!

ng-required não aceita. Onde este if encontra nada, mas também não deixa passar se não tiver nada selecionado. Nem o Alert ele dá... POG total.

```
$scope.SelecionaCategoria = function () {



            if (($scope.escolhido.categoria_comida_cod_categoria_com).length === null) {
                slert('É PRECISO UMA CATEGORIA');
            } else {

                $ionicLoading.show();

                var url = "?cod_categoria=" + $scope.escolhido.categoria_comida_cod_categoria_com + "&categoria=" + $scope.escolhido.categoria_comida_nome + ""
                console.log(url);


                var encodedurl = encodeURI(url);
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                window.localStorage.setItem("cod_categoria", $scope.escolhido.categoria_comida_cod_categoria_com);

                $state.go('nhaac.formDelicias');

            }
```